# How can I add multiple pointcuts to tx:advice in xml format?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, transactions, spring-aop

I want to add multiple pointcuts in a single advice like as follows

```
<tx:advice id="txAdvice" transaction-manager="transactionManager"> 
    <tx:attributes> 
        <tx:method name="add*" propagation="REQUIRED" /> 
    </tx:attributes> 
</tx:advice> 
<aop:config> 
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcut1" 
        expression="execution(* com.service.svc1.*(..))" /> 
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcut2" 
        expression="execution(* com.service.svc2.*(..))" /> 
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" 
        pointcut-ref="pointcut1" /> 
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" 
        pointcut-ref="pointcut2" /> 
</aop:config>
```

What is the proper solution to do that? I don't want to use '||' in expression because of some reasons.

Or can I use "()" in expression? Something like as follow.

```
"( execution(* com.service.svc1.*(..)) && bean(bean1) ) || ( execution(* com.service.svc1.*(..)) || bean(bean2) )"
```

Comment: Not sure on the question , but from the [documenation reference :7.3.2 Declaring a pointcut](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s03.html) : *When combining pointcut sub-expressions, '&&' is awkward within an XML document, and so the keywords 'and', 'or' and 'not' can be used in place of '&&', '||' and '!' respectively*. Is this your requirement ?

Comment: @R.G No. I want to use expression like (xx AND xx) OR (xx AND xx) but it showed the error indicated that brackets cannot be used.

Comment: @R.G Or how can I add multiple pointcuts with tx advice?

Comment: Do go through [7.2.3.2 Combining pointcut expressions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s02.html#aop-common-pointcuts) and [7.2.3.3 Sharing common pointcut definitions](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/3.0.0.M4/reference/html/ch07s02.html#aop-common-pointcuts) . You can combine the pointcuts as described

Comment: @R.G I dont want just combine the pointcuts with and, or, not. I want combine the pointcuts with brackets.

Comment: I think I know what is wrong with your pointcut: ambiguous parameter binding. But in order to say for sure, I would like to see your exact error message and config without `...`, not just a vague statement like _"error indicated that brackets cannot be used_". I cannot debug your statement, it is neither code nor an error message. Furthermore, deliberate omissions like `...` in your sample configuration shall only elicit wild speculation, nobody can analyse `...`.

Comment: One more thing: Parentheses for `(A && B) || (C && D)` are optional, because AND takes precedence over OR anyway. Only if you need something other than default precedence, you need to use parentheses, e.g. `(A || B) && (C || D)`.

Comment: @kriegaex parentheses cannot be added in the expression. This will cause syntax error.

Comment: @kriegaex I finally used the method stated in my question.

Comment: Which method? Your comment is unclear. If you think you solved the problem you asked the StackOverflow community about, please return something to same community by posting a compresehsive answer, explaining how you did it. Besides, your statement about being unable to use parentheses in pointcuts in XML config files is simply false. I tried, it works beautifully, also in connection with `and`, `or`. So in this case, the problem seems to sit in front of the computer, writing pointcuts with syntax errors - which is exactly why we asked you for an MCVE.

Comment: @kriegaex 
I used the method like this:

<aop:pointcut id="pointcut1" 
        expression="execution(* com.service.svc1.*(..))" /> 
    <aop:pointcut id="pointcut2" 
        expression="execution(* com.service.svc2.*(..))" /> 
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" 
        pointcut-ref="pointcut1" /> 
    <aop:advisor advice-ref="txAdvice" 
        pointcut-ref="pointcut2" />

Comment: Please write an answer for your solution, not a comment. The code is unreadable like that. Besides, you still did not show examples of pointcuts for which allegedly parentheses did not work in your case. I.e., you make a claim without supporting it with facts. That way, nobody can verify your statement.